# Put arrow left and arrow right in a HTML element

Tags: html, css

I want to make something like this but what I don't know how I can add these right and left arrows.

[image]

I tried to write with style `inline-block` or `inline`, but it didn't work.

Here is my code:

```html
<div style="color: #ffffff">
  <p style="text-align: center; background-color:#1c3c41; ">Male</p>
</div>
```

Comment: where are the left and right arrows in your code?

Comment: i removed it because, didn't worked.I maked a <div style="display: inline-block;">«</div>, but it didn't worked

Comment: @dmiller8369: Try my solution. No need to add any thing in HTML, All is handled by CSS

Answer (score 1):

With your current HTML Step Try Below Code. I have used CSS entities and pseudo elements:

```
.container::before{
  content:"\003C";
  display:inline;
  margin-left:1rem;
  
}

.container::after{
  content:"\003E";
  display:inline;
  margin-right:1rem;
  
}

.container{
  display:flex;
  width:200px;
  background:#000;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
  border-radius:0.5rem
}
```

**WORKING CODE:**

```css
.container::before{
  content:"\003C";
  display:inline;
  margin-left:1rem;
}

.container::after{
  content:"\003E";
  display:inline;
  margin-right:1rem;
  
}

.container{
  display:flex;
  width:200px;
  background:#000;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
  border-radius:0.5rem
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="color: #ffffff">
  <p style="text-align: center;">Male</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, for you support!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you are looking for just paste this in your HTML and you will get the desired result

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div
        style="height: 30px; color: white; background-color: #1c3c41; display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;">
        <div style="display: inline;">
            <img style="filter: invert(100%);" src="https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/860/860790.svg" alt=""
                width="16" height="16">
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline;">
            <p style="display: inline; text-align: center; background-color:#1c3c41; ">Male</p>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline;">
            <img style="filter: invert(100%);" src="https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/54/54833.svg" alt="" width="16" height="16">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, for you support!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to achieve what you want

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: horizontal;
  width: 200px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 7.5px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.arrow {
  border-radius:50%;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 2px 6px;
}

.arrow:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrow"><</div>
  <div class="text">male</div>
  <div class="arrow">></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, for you support!